# Firefox extension to write a script in a web page

Tags: javascript, firefox, scripting, html

I am new to firefox extension building and would like some help on an application I am creating. I would like to create a firefox extension that on choosing to activate the firefox extension, opens a new tab and sends the script to the page to display a certain amount of text or perform some sort of activity.
The only problem with this being that I do not know how to implement any of this in the javascript or xul file.

I have created the menu option in the javascript file and this is called from the XUL file.
Can anyone help me create the script in the web page?

Thank you

Comment: "display a certain amount of text or perform some sort of activity" Could you be more precise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the script you're looking to run is JavaScript, I'd recommend just using the [GreaseMonkey](http://www.greasespot.net/) [add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748).

Comment: Can Greasemonkey really do what (s)he wants?  I.e. open a new tab and stuff?

Comment: Javascript can't explicitly say to open a new tab since not all browser have tabs, but user preferences can make it so that _blank targeted links open in a tab rather than window.